# Add type constraint to derived type F# (This code is not sufficiently generic)

Tags: generics, f#, polymorphism, type-constraints

I have this interface:

```
type IMovingFunc< 'T > =
    abstract member Add : 'T -> unit
```

Now I want to create a generic type that implements Add function and uses (+) operator:

```
type MovingSum< ^T >(initial : ^T) =
    let mutable sum = initial

    interface IMovingFunc< ^T> with
        member inline this.Add x = sum <- sum + x
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

> This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable ^T when ^T : (static member ( + ) : ^T * ^T -> ^T) could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.

I've tried adding type constraint to MovingSum but it didn't help:

```
type MovingSum< ^T when ^T : (static member ( + ) : ^T * ^T -> ^T)>(initial : ^T)
```

Could you please tell me how to fix this or is there other way to achieve this?

Comment: Types can't have type parameters with statically resolved constraints. Only functions.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That's not actually correct, although it might be better if it were...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Fyodor in the comments, types cannot have statically resolved constraints in the same way as functions (mainly because static constraints are handled using inlining - and you cannot really inline a whole type).

One way to address this is to make the constraint explicit in the type and then create a function with static member constraint that captures the functionality and passes it to the type.

In your example, you need the `+` operator, so we can add `adder` as a parameter of the type:

```
type MovingSum<'T>(initial:'T, adder:'T -> 'T -> 'T) =
    let mutable sum = initial
    interface IMovingFunc<'T> with
        member this.Add x = sum <- adder sum x
```

This does not require static member constraints, but you need to provide the extra parameter when creating `MovingSum`. This is not too bad, but you can avoid that by defining an inline function that creates `MovingSum` and captures the `+` operator:

```
let inline movingSum initial = 
  MovingSum(initial, fun a b -> a + b) :> IMovingFunc<_>
```

Answer (score 7):

Tomas's answer is good.  However, for completeness: it *is* possible to use statically resolved type parameters on types:

```
type MovingSum< ^T when ^T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^T -> ^T)>(initial : ^T) =
    let mutable sum = initial

    member inline this.Add(x:^T) = sum <- sum + x

let m = MovingSum(1) in m.Add(3) // works!
```

But note that:

1. Member constraints need to be included where the parameter is declared.
2. I get a few spurious warnings here, indicating that maybe this language feature is not fully-baked...
3. This doesn't help you anyway, since interface members can't be inlined - given a value of an interface type, the compiler doesn't have any way to determine the runtime type that implements the interface, and so it's impossible to know what implementation to inline.